# NGRX 7 - Stuck in endless loop even on dispatching new action of different type in ngrx/effects

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am trying to implement login in @angular/core 7.1.0 and @ngrx/store 7.0. Now problem is when I dispatch a new Login action from my login component, it is correctly listen in Login effect, but even on dispatching new LoginSuccess action, the login action stuck in endless loop until the LoginFailure action occured.(When i stop the backend service).

**auth.effects.ts**

```js
  @Effect()
  login$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActionTypes.LOGIN),
    map((action: Login) => action.payload),
    switchMap(payload => {
      console.log('SwitchMap: Login [Effect]: payload', payload);
      return this.authService.login(payload.email, payload.password).pipe(
        map((loginResponse: LoginResponse) => {
          console.log('loginResponse:', loginResponse);
          return new LoginSuccess(loginResponse);
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          console.log(error);
          return of(new LoginFailure({ error: error }));
        })
      );
    })
  );


  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  loginSuccess: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS),
    map((action: LoginSuccess) => action.payload),
    tap((loginResponse: LoginResponse) => {
      console.log('Login_Success [Effect]: payload', loginResponse);
      localStorage.setItem('accessToken', loginResponse.accessToken);
      localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', loginResponse.refreshToken);
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(loginResponse.user));
      // if (loginResponse.user.isSuperAdmin) {
      //   this.router.navigate(['/admin/dashboard']);
      // } else {
      //   this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      // }
    })
  );
```

**login.component.ts**

```
onSubmit() {
    // Will triggered only when form is submitted
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      console.log('Form Submitted: values', this.loginPayload);
      this.store.dispatch(new Login({ email: this.loginPayload.username, password: this.loginPayload.password }));
      this.loginForm.resetForm();
    }
  }
```

[image]

**Edit: New Finding**
When I am returning a http call (from authService) observable like:

```
return this.http.put<LoginResponse>('/api/v1/entrance/login', body);
```

this bug is happening (i.e request get stuck in endless loop). But when I am faking the api by retunring new observable like below then it is not.

```js
   return new Observable<LoginResponse>((observer) => {
      if (email === 'superadmin@xyz.com' && password === 'abc123') {
        const data: LoginResponse = {
          accessToken: 'dadsfjhsjdahlfjh#324jk34h23343kkjlsadsads',
          refreshToken: 'jfjsdg-32432-sdf4543-sdff4234-3424-3434',
          user: {
            email: 'superadmin@xyz.com',
            name: 'Superadmin',
            isSuperAdmin: true,
            id: 1,
            isLdapUser: false,
            isAdUser: false,
            lastSeenAt: new Date().getTime()
          }
        };
        observer.next(data);
      } else {
        observer.error({ error: 'invalid credentials.' });
      }
      observer.complete();
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

After lot of debugging finally I found the bug:,
It was in my authorizeRequest intercepter. Previously my code of this interceptor was:

```js
   intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.store.select('auth').pipe(
      switchMap((authState: fromAuth.State) => {
        if (authState.user && authState.accessToken) {
          const secureReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authState.accessToken)
          });
          return next.handle(secureReq);
        } else {
          return next.handle(req);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

In this whenever the auth state changes, new request is dispatched, hence causing the endless loop. To solve this I have to use **take(1) operator**,

So my code now becomes:

```js
   intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.store.select('auth').pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap((authState: fromAuth.State) => {
        if (authState.user && authState.accessToken) {
          const secureReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authState.accessToken)
          });
          return next.handle(secureReq);
        } else {
          return next.handle(req);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```js
  // Listen for the 'LOGIN' action
  @Effect()
  login$: Observable <Action> = this
    .actions$
    .pipe(ofType<authAction.Login>(authAction.LoginActionTypes.LOGIN), mergeMap(action => this.authService.login(action.payload).pipe(
    // If successful, dispatch success action with result
    map(data => ({type: authAction.LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS})),
    // If request fails, dispatch failed action
    catchError(() => of({type: authAction.LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_FAIL})))));

  /* Pass { dispatch: false } to the decorator to prevent dispatching.
  Sometimes you don't want effects to dispatch an action, for example when you only want to log or navigate.
  But when an effect does not dispatch another action, the browser will crash because the effect is both 'subscribing' to and 'dispatching'
  the exact same action, causing an infinite loop. To prevent this, add { dispatch: false } to the decorator. */
  @Effect({dispatch: false})
  loginSuccess$ = this
    .actions$
    .pipe(ofType(authAction.LoginActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS), tap(() => this.router.navigate(['/portal'])));
```

You dont need to use return this.authService.login or return action type this approach is better and more clean since you dont have to new everytime you want to dispatch action type

And my opinion is maybe this.loginForm.resetForm(); line trigger you action being dispatch multiple time so I would suggest you change into this

```js
onSubmit() {
    // Will triggered only when form is submitted
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      console.log('Form Submitted: values', this.loginPayload);
      this.store.dispatch(new Login({ email: this.loginPayload.username, password: this.loginPayload.password }));
    }
   this.loginForm.resetForm();
  }
```

My mock login service

```js
  login(userCredentials: any): Observable<any> {
    if (userCredentials.account !== 'test') {
      return throwError('Invalid username or password');
    }
    return of({name: 'User'}); //change your code here
  }
```

I'm using return of() to let observable know that I have received data I need so effect dont need to subscribe on the observable stream any more

Please let me know if you need any help

Comment: When you use this type of statement: action => this.authService.login(action.payload) , as far as I know you internally return it, just return keyword is hidden.

Comment: @DeepakPandey yes I know. Just my suggest to make the code cleanner. Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: No it didn't solve my problem, still login request are stuck in endless loop, when I stop the backend server and LoginFailure Action is returned then only it stops.

Comment: @DeepakPandey so adding @Effect({dispatch: false}) in your effect did not solve the problem ?

Comment: I have already @Effect({ dispatch: false }) in loginSuccess where I  do not dispatch any action. Problem is in login effect, where even after dispatching LoginSuccess, it gets stuck in a loop, and login service is called again and again and new LoginSuccess action is dispatched, untill, I don't stop the backend

Comment: I have edited the question with some new findings, can you help me now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192543/discussion-between-deepak-pandey-and-ngo-hung-phuc).